Add and resize with rectangle from one Picture box and Another picturebox to label in run time with VB.NET
I trying to add and resize with rectangle from one Picture box barcode and Another picture box QR to label in run time with VB.NET
is there any other method or solution I can do add and resize with rectangle like the gif file below ?
Please Guide me
Thanks
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports ZXing
Imports ZXing.Common

<Assembly: CLSCompliant(True)>
Partial Public Class LabelWYSIWYG
    Inherits UserControl



    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        '' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        'Label1.Size = 80,50
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 60)
        ' Populate the dropdown with supported barcode formats
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("EAN_13")
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("CODABAR")
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("CODE_39")
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("CODE_93")
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("CODE_128")
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("EAN_8")
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("ITF")
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("UPC_A")
        ComboBox1D.Items.Add("UPC_E")
        ComboBox1D.SelectedIndex = -1
        ComboBox2D.Items.Add("AZTEC")
        ComboBox2D.Items.Add("DATA_MATRIX")
        ComboBox2D.Items.Add("PDF_417")
        ComboBox2D.Items.Add("QR_CODE")
        ComboBox2D.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
    Private Sub GenerateBarcode1D()
        Dim writer As New BarcodeWriter()
        Dim format As BarcodeFormat
        Select Case Me.ComboBox1D.Text
            Case "CODABAR"
                format = BarcodeFormat.CODABAR
            Case "CODE_39"
                format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_39
            Case "CODE_93"
                format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_93
            Case "CODE_128"
                format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
            Case "EAN_8"
                format = BarcodeFormat.EAN_8
            Case "EAN_13"
                format = BarcodeFormat.EAN_13
            Case "ITF"
                format = BarcodeFormat.ITF
            Case "UPC_A"
                format = BarcodeFormat.UPC_A
            Case "UPC_E"
                format = BarcodeFormat.UPC_E
        End Select
        writer.Format = format
        Dim options As New EncodingOptions()
        options.Height = txtBH.Value
        options.Width = txtBW.Value
        options.Margin = 10
        writer.Options = options
        Dim barcodeBitmap As Bitmap = writer.Write(txtBarcode.Text)
        Dim finalBitmap As New Bitmap(CInt(txtBH.Value), CInt(txtBW.Value))
        Dim graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(finalBitmap)
        Try
            ' Clear the background with white color
            graphics.Clear(Color.White)

            ' Draw the barcode onto the final bitmap
            Dim barcodeX As Integer = (txtBW.Value)
            Dim barcodeY As Integer = (txtBH.Value)
            graphics.DrawImage(barcodeBitmap, barcodeX, barcodeY)
        Finally
            ' Dispose graphics object to free resources
            graphics.Dispose()
        End Try
        PictureBoxBarcode.Image = finalBitmap
    End Sub
    Private Sub GenerateBarcode2D()
        Dim writer As New BarcodeWriter()
        Dim format As BarcodeFormat
        Select Case Me.ComboBox2D.Text
            Case "AZTEC"
                format = BarcodeFormat.AZTEC
            Case "DATA_MATRIX"
                format = BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX
            Case "PDF_417"
                format = BarcodeFormat.PDF_417
            Case "QR_CODE"
                format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
        End Select
        writer.Format = format
        Dim options As New EncodingOptions()
        options.Height = txtBH.Value
        options.Width = txtBW.Value
        options.Margin = 10
        writer.Options = options
        Dim barcodeBitmap As Bitmap = writer.Write(txtBarcode.Text)
        Dim finalBitmap As New Bitmap(CInt(txtBH.Value), CInt(txtBW.Value))
        Dim graphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(finalBitmap)
        Try
            ' Clear the background with white color
            graphics.Clear(Color.White)

            ' Draw the barcode onto the final bitmap
            Dim barcodeX As Integer = (txtBW.Value)
            Dim barcodeY As Integer = (txtBH.Value)
            graphics.DrawImage(barcodeBitmap, barcodeX, barcodeY)
        Finally
            ' Dispose graphics object to free resources
            graphics.Dispose()
        End Try
        PictureBoxQr.Image = finalBitmap
    End Sub
End Class

#Region "EventArgs extension and event delegates"

''' <summary>
''' Class to extend EventArgs with a cancel parameter.
''' </summary>
Public Class LabelWYSIWYGEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="LabelWYSIWYGEventArgs"/> is cancel.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value><c>true</c> if cancel; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>

    Private _cancel As Boolean
    Public Property Cancel As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._cancel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            Me._cancel = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Delegate Sub LabelWYSIWYGOnOpen(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LabelWYSIWYGEventArgs)
Public Delegate Sub LabelWYSIWYGOnSave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As LabelWYSIWYGEventArgs)


#End Region ' EventArgs extension and event delegates


result interface in usercontrol

Desired result like below file gif

